# 2 hop SSH port forward

Tags: ssh, portforwarding

I've been trying to setup the following port forward configuration using 1 (or 2) lines, but with no success:

3 Machines involved; local machine[`local`], prod machine[`prod`], 3rd party machine[`service`]. `Prod` has (http) access to an API hosted on `service` and I (`local`) have ssh access to `prod`. So for development purposes I am trying to setup a tunnel to `service` via `prod` so I can issue a cURL command to some `local` port and have the request hit the `service` endpoint.

I'm pretty sure I've done this exact thing a few years ago with a single `ssh` command, but so far I've been unable to replicate it. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Better post this on server fault ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ssh -Nnt -L<localport number>:service:<service port number> <username>@prod &`

should do it and stay open in the background, if I understand what you're trying to do. This will send requests on `<localport number>` to `<service port number>` on `service` through `prod`.

Comment: what if you needed to specify a `.pem` for `prod` to contact `service`?

Comment: @WalrustheCat No idea -- but [maybe this Q&A answers it for you](https://serverfault.com/questions/516431/create-an-ssh-tunnel-with-authentication-keys-syntax). If it doesn't and searching around doesn't turn up one that does, open a new question!